Split Pandas dataframa on multiple delimiters
I want to split the following data using pandas at following delimiters and save the file in excel format:
":", "Product", ",", "Qty", "-", "\", "Joining"
My sample excel file data:
ColumnA
Tr. # 1 : Product XZA123, Qty 15 - Priya Singh | Jr. Sales Exe. | Bangalore | 2024 Joining
Tr. # 2 : Product BCD987, Qty 8 - Anjali Kumar - Sales Exe. - Chennai | 2023 Joining
.
.
.
Tr. # 6 : Product VWX987, Qty 20 - Aditi Malhotra - Sales Exe. - Delhi | 2022 Joining
Tr. # 7 : Product YZA321, Qty 22 - Rajesh Kulkarni | Sr. Sales Exe. | Chennai | 2023 Joining
Tr. # 8 : Product BCD432, Qty 9 - Meera Gupta - Jr. Sales Exe. - Mumbai | 2024 Joining
Tr. # 9 : Product HIJ876, Qty 15 - Sanya Iyer - Sr. Sales Exe. - Hyderabad | 2023 Joining
Tr. # 10 : Product KLM543, Qty 10 - Mohit Verma | Jr. Sales Exe. | Pune | 2024 Joining
Tr. # 11 : Product NOP432, Qty 5 - Priyanka Roy - Sales Exe. - Kolkata | 2022 Joining
Tr. # 12 : Product TUV654, Qty 18 - Neha Sharma - Jr. Sales Exe. - Mumbai | 2023 Joining
Tr. # 1077 :  Product VWX210, Qty 16 - Ritu Sharma - Sales Exe. - Chennai | 2024 Joining
Tr. # 1078 :  Product YZA654, Qty 13 - Karthik Reddy | Sr. Sales Exe. | Hyderabad | 2022 Joining
Tr. # 1079 :  Product BCD321, Qty 10 - Shreya Iyer - Jr. Sales Exe. - Mumbai | 2023 Joining
Tr. # 1080 :  Product HIJ432, Qty 19 - Amit Patel - Sr. Sales Exe. - Delhi | 2022 Joining

For some reason it is not splitting. I have total of 1080 lines of data in excel and output is 3245 lines.
Here is the code I have written:
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1080)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\node\Desktop\1300.xlsx")
print(df.ColumnA.str.split(r":Product |,|Qty|-|\| Joining",expand=True).add_prefix('Cols_'))

file_name='C:\Users\shah\Desktop\myfile.xlsx'
df.to_excel(file_name)


Here is the output I am getting:
                            Cols_0 Cols_1 Cols_2  \
0         Tr. # 1 : Product XZA123           15    
1         Tr. # 2 : Product BCD987            8    
2         Tr. # 3 : Product JKL321           25    
3         Tr. # 4 : Product MNO654           30
.
.
.
.
                                                 Cols_3            Cols_4  \
0      Priya Singh | Jr. Sales Exe. | Bangalore | 20...              None   
1                                         Anjali Kumar        Sales Exe.    
2                                          Aarav Patel    Jr. Sales Exe.    
3       Ishaan Desai | Sales Exe. | Pune | 2024 Joining              None   
4                                          Nitya Mehra    Sr. Sales Exe.    
5  

The code is also giving following error on saving excel file:
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

How can this be rectified ?
